# Como mudar os diretórios padrões de instalação dos pacotes pelo NuGet?

Tags: visual-studio-2013

Em um projeto ***ASP.NET MVC***, é possível especificar em que pastas serão instalados os ***plugins*** ***Javascript*** e **css**, como ***Bootstrap***, diferentemente dos padrões ***Content*** e ***Scripts***?

***Content*** e ***Scripts*** são os diretórios padrões para esses arquivos quando instalados em um projeto pelo ***NuGet*** ou ***Package Manager Console***. É possível mudar ou isso é uma configuração de cada pacote?

Se sim, como?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

É uma configuração de cada pacote. Se você preferir, é possível baixar os pacotes, editá-los localmente para seguir as convenções que você precisa e disponibilizá-los em um feed privado.

Answer (score 4):

Não.

A configuração de destino dos arquivos é definida pelo pacote, e normalmente segue um padrão pra não virar bagunça.

O que você pode fazer, como dito pelo @viniciushana, é criar seus próprios pacotes com suas configurações, mas não creio que isso seja produtivo.